# How to judge the isomorphism of two drawings of same graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

We say two drawings of a graph are **isomorphic** if there is a **homeomorphism** of the surface that maps one drawing to the other. But in actual operation, I find it quite difficult to determine whether two drawings are isomorphic. I don’t know how to describe homeomorphism.
For example, the following two drawings both show one graph $K_6$ on the plane:

[image]
[image]
Are these two drawing isomorphic? why? Is there a more operational way to judge?

The definition of drawing isomorphism comes from the following book, which is also the first monograph of Crossing number.

[Crossing numbers of graphs](https://hk1lib.org/book/3420010/73e100)

Comment: In the plane? No. -- Any homeomorphism of the plane must keep infinity fixed, so to speak. In particular, the unbounded faces in both drawings must have the same properties. But in the first drawing, it is incident with three vertices and in the second only with two. -- If you look at the sphere instead of the plane, things look different.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Thank you for your hint, but it may change on the sphere, I did not think clearly

Comment: @Arthur   Yes,  but graph isomorphism does not mean drawing isomorphism

Comment: So, if I understood this correctly, a drawing isomorphism is like a graph isomorphism with two types of vertices: true vertices and intersections. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Arthur   Although the general definition is not mentioned in this way, I feel what you say is right.

Comment: I don’t know if there is any mathematics software that can do the judgment. I go to the mathematica stack to ask this question

Comment: @licheng Yes, on the sphere, these drawings are isomorphic: In the second drawing, just bring a point in one of the two triangle faces to infinity

Comment: @Arthur No, even with no intersections, two drawings of the same graph might not be isomorphic. For instance, [this graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=36261) also has an embedding where the external face has length $5$ (just "fold in" one of the triangles) and this is isomorphic to the given one, which has no faces of length $5$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I assume your last sentence was intended to say "this is *not* isomorphic to the given one"?

Comment: Yes, that; regretabbly I cannot edit the comment.

Comment: @Arthur I just wanted to emphasize that drawing isomorphisms are not the same as "isomorphisms with two types of vertices: true vertices and intersections".

Comment: @MishaLavrov You're right. I'm apparently just tired. And also just introduced to the concept of drawing isomorphisms today. Not a good combo for being obstinate. Yet here I am being exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem with testing if two *graphs* are isomorphic is that there's so many potential ways to match them up. With graph drawings, there is no combinatorial explosion - at least not when the graph drawing is $2$-connected. (If not, then we can still find isomorphisms between blocks efficiently, but it might be hard to figure out which blocks correspond.)

Treat a graph drawing as a plane embedding of a graph, in which the intersections are merely another type of vertex. If the graph drawing is $2$-connected, then each face has a *face walk* which visits all the vertices in order around the face, which is unique up to changing the starting point and reversing the order.

Let's make two initial guesses about the drawing isomorphism:

1. Pick a length-$k$ face of one drawing, and guess which length-$k$ face of the other drawing it corresponds to.
2. Pick face walks $v_1, \dots, v_k, v_1$ and $w_1, \dots, w_k, w_1$ of the two faces, and guess that $v_i$ corresponds to $w_i$ for $i=1, 2, \dots, k$.

Then if our guesses were right, the rest of the isomorphism is determined. The other face touching edge $v_i v_{i+1}$ must correspond to the other face touching edge $w_i w_{i+1}$, and knowing two corresponding vertices tells us how the rest of their face walks correspond. We can repeat this to grow the region where we know the isomorphism, one face at a time. Either we reach a contradiction (two faces that must match have different lengths, or two vertices that must match have different types), or we find an isomorphism.

We can try every possible way to make these guesses, and see if they work out. In the plane, we have a shortcut: the unbounded faces must correspond.